# Problema ao deixar container rolável usando Listview

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá, estou criando um feed e nesse feed estou usando Listview.builder, tenho alguns botões que servem como os filtros, porém quero que os botões de filtros rolem junto com as postagens. Já tentei envolver tudo dentro do ScrollView porém sem sucesso.

Aqui meu [Feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQV6Q.png)

Segue o código do ListView.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final CollectionReference post =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');
return Material(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      FilterButtons(size: size), //Os meus filtros
      Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: post.snapshots(),
        builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                      streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                        child: Container(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 176, 143, 229),
                          height: size.height * 0.25,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                });
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }),
      )),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Você pode tentar dois caminhos... **1)** Dentro do stream builder criar uma lista com os posts que deseja, e incluir no index 0, algum valor "vazio"para quando for construir a lista, você saber que no index 0 "vazio" você deverá retornar seu Widget de botões e nos demais casos a estrutura do post. **2)** É mais complexo, mas você pode adicionar um scrollController na sua lista e depois observar as mudanças no scroll para movimentar manualmente teu widget de botões.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a primeira solução que foi apontada pelo [Matheus](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/87785/matheus-ribeiro) nos comentários, você pode fazer um controle no seu ListView, e exibir o item dos botões de filtros como primeiro da lista.

Para isso, algumas modificações devem ser feitas:

- Agora o número de elementos da sua ListView foi acrescido de um. Logo, adicione um item a mais à contagem para reservar um espaço para ele:

`itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length + 1, // Adicionado +1`

- No seu construtor de cada elemento, podemos verificar se o índice é 0, e se for, retornar a lista de filtros. Caso contrário, retorna-se o resto da lista. É preciso atentar-se que agora o índice 0 refere-se ao widget de botões, e o primeiro elemento da lista que vem do SnapShot agora é de índice 1. Ou seja, você deve utilizar `index-1` nos lugares que usava `index`.

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == 0) { // O primeiro item da lista é o especificado por você.
                      return FilterButtons(size: size);
                  }
                  final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                      streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index - 1]; // Lembre-se de utilizar index - 1 aonde for necessário.
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                        child: Container(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 176, 143, 229),
                          height: size.height * 0.25,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
```